# How to find the ID Name of a JLabel Array in Java with MouseListener

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

***What I have done.***

I have created an array of JLabel like that:

```
static JLabel numbers[] = new JLabel[25];
```

I Have given to each of the `numbers[each of this]` a random number between 1 and 80.

I have added to each of `numbers[]` array a `MouseListener`.

I want to make something like, once I press a specific label to change itself background. But to do that I have to detect the ID of the `JLabel` has been pressed.

***The Question:***

How can I get the name or the number of the array on `JLabel` that has been pressed?

So far I only know how to get the text from it with the following code:

```
JLabel l = (JLabel) e.getSource();
int strNumber = Integer.parseInt(l.getText());
```

I want the ID of `numbers[THIS]`, not the text but the number of array.

In Button listener, I know how to do that, but in MouseListener is not working...

(At least with the methods I tried to...(`e.getSource().getName();` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the array, you've got a reference to the pressed JLabel: `e.getSource();`, so simply iterate through the array to find the one that matches the other. e.g.,

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; numbers++) {
        if (numbers[i] == source) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// here index either == the array item of interest or -1 if no match
```

Side issue: that array should **not** be static, and that it is static suggests that you have some design issues with your program that need to be fixed.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks a lot! I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes.. because of my new account I have delay :)

Comment: @Erick: you're welcome. Note that the array should not be static, and you would do well to make it an instance array.